# Folders with Icons on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, folders, icon

Recently, I organized all of the apps on my iPad, and came to a realization: it would be great if I could make the folders have their own icons. What I mean is this (right), as supposed to this (left):

[image: Before and after of the folder's icon.]

I have already looked for some ways to do this, but the only thing I've found is something called is a Cydia tweak called TinyGrid, which does let you customize the icons of the folders, but not change the image for them (you can change the size, etc.). Currently, my iPad is not jailbroken, but if the solution is jailbreak-only, I may be willing to jailbreak it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me just put this out there: any tweak that tweaks the appearance like this is going to require that you jailbreak ;)

While not exactly what you're looking, A3Tweaks has achieved a somewhat similar alternative to what you're describing! It's called "Apex 2 (iOS 7)". It is a paid app, but at $2.99 it's not entirely unreasonable. However, it is slightly different that being just a folder with one icon. Rather than wasting your or my time writing out exactly what it does, what it looks like, or how it functions, you can check out an excellent write-up at [iDownloadBlog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/05/23/apex-2-cydia/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just watched the video, though, and it doesn't quite seem like what I'm looking for. Not sure if it's possible at all, anyway. Again, thanks though.

Comment: Understood! I just remember looking for something like what you want. I saw that tweak, and I said, "Meh, good enough" :P Since then, I haven't found anything like what you're talking about in any of the default repositories (and I've been jailbreaking for a while now, haha). Good luck!